# ruby on rails: name of person on hover on a each.do

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to have the name of the students appear on the student's image on a each do function on ruby on rails. I am noob so I apologize if this is a stupid question!

```
<div id="studentIndex">
  <div class="page-content-wrapper">
    <h1 class="page-header">Student Index</h1>
     <div class="index">
      <% @students.each do |student| %>
      <%= link_to image_tag(student.img_url), student_path(student)  %>
      <figcaption> <%= @student.name %> </figcaption>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the name of the student to only show on hover? You'd have to use javascript to have dynamic behavior on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@student` is an array of object and you are storing each object of array in student by each. so you need to do

```
 <div id="studentIndex">
  <div class="page-content-wrapper">
    <h1 class="page-header">Student Index</h1>
     <div class="index">
      <% @students.each do |student| %>
      <%= link_to image_tag(student.img_url), student_path(student)  %>
      <figcaption> <%= student.name %> </figcaption>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

OR if you want student name and image to be print and when user clicks on name/image they need student's show then you need to pass block in link_to helper method by below way

```
    <div id="studentIndex">
          <div class="page-content-wrapper">
            <h1 class="page-header">Student Index</h1>
             <div class="index">
              <% @students.each do |student| %>
              <%= link_to student_path(student) do  %>
                <%= image_tag(student.img_url) %>
               <figcaption> <%= student.name %> </figcaption>
             <%end%>
              <% end %>
            </div>
```

Hope this will help you.. If you have any queries feel free to comment :)

Answer (score 3):

`@student` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere. Based on what you've provided, use `<%= student.name %>` rather than `<%= @student.name %>` when outputting the name.